# Mercurial not displaying correct commit time on sourceforge

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, sourceforge

I am running mercurial on my sourceforge project. I am updating the repo using tortiseHg on windows. Whenever I update files, their commit times are always off by a few hours. For example, I just updated a file about 5 minutes ago, and it says that it was updated 6 hours ago. The file I updated about 6 hours ago says it was updated about 30 minutes ago.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to a time zone difference between you and the sourceforge servers where both or either one of you is reporting local time?

Comment: Thats what I thought too. I made sure my time zone is set correctly under sourceforge/account settings. I couldn't find anywhere else to set me time.